# how to get ALL the objects in a database that are NOT FOR REPLICATION?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication, metadata

`“Not for Replication”` is a property which can be set for different objects like `check constraints`, 
`Foreign Key constraints`, 
`Triggers` , `Identity columns`
**etc** while using SQL Server Replication.

What are ALL object types that can be NOT FOR REPLICATION?
How can I find them?

For those object types I have mentioned above I am putting a script together:

> identity columns

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
, i.name AS [Index]
, p.partition_number
, p.rows AS [Row Count]
, i.type_desc AS [Index Type]
,K.increment_value as IncrementValue
,K.last_value as LastValue
,K.seed_value as SeedValue
,k.is_nullable
,k.is_identity
,k.is_filestream
,k.is_replicated
,k.is_not_for_replication

FROM sys.partitions p

INNER JOIN sys.indexes i 
ON p.object_id = i.object_id
AND p.index_id = i.index_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns K
ON P.object_id = K.object_id

where  1=1
  AND  i.index_id < 2 -- GET ONLY THE CLUSTERED INDEXES - IF EXISTS ANY
ORDER BY [Schema], [Table], [Index]
```

> triggers

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
,t.*

FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.triggers t
ON p.object_id = t.parent_id
```

> check constraints

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
,c.*

FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
        ON p.object_id = t.object_id

INNER JOIN sys.check_constraints c
        ON t.object_id = c.parent_object_id
```

> foreign key constraints

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
,fk.*

FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
        ON p.object_id = t.object_id

INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON t.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
```

Please note that I have used [sys.partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and that is not a requirement for this question, but I like to have an idea of the space each object occupies and where it is physically located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row Level [Security Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-security-policy-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) have a NOT FOR REPLICATION property too, allowing the replication agents to bypass the policy.  But I think that's it, at least those are the only objects with is_not_for_replciation column in the catalog.

```
select object_name(object_id) object_name, c.name column_name
from sys.all_columns c
where c.name like '%replication%'
order by column_name
```